# I can't connect two bluetooth devices at the same time in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, keyboard, bluetooth, 22.04

I have a situation where I can't connect to two bluetooth devices at the same time in Ubuntu 22.04. I've tried this with several different devices but what I really need to connect are

- Keychron K8 pro wireless keyboard
- Soundcore Life Q30 headphones

Whatever device connects first gets to work, and the second device either wont connect at all, or will connect but fail to work and register in the OS. The error I get is "org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-create-socket." I've tried several solutions posted here or in stackoverflow to no avail. Modifying /etc/bluetooth/main.conf to support multiple devices not working.

Comment: Seems a pulseaudio issue. Did you already check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1336059/349837), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258076/209677) or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/721697/209677)?

Comment: Well, bluetooth headphones work flawlessly if you connect them before the keyboard. Pulseaudio bluetooth is working fine it seems and is up to the last version. It looks like a different issue related to having several devices connected at the same time.

Comment: It is possible that the Bluetooth device in the computer do not support multi devices at once. This was an issue in some very old Bluetooth devices.

Comment: It's a Realtek® RTL8822BE that indeed supports multidevice. It looks more like a drivers or SO problem, because for a few minutes I actually manage to make bot devices work, but then one of them stops working (either the keyboard or the headphones). My solution right now is always using one of them wired. Thanks for your insight, folks.

Comment: I have the same exact problem on Ubuntu 22.04 and Keychron K8. I am also using a Bose headphone QC 35 II. Headphones work fine, but the Keyboard started having this issues recently. It never did on Ubuntu 20 or Debian.

I also, for some reason, made it work for a few days, then it stopped again. On bluetoothctl it will be like

[NEW] Device DC:2C:26:0E:24:72 Keychron K8
[CHG] Device DC:2C:26:0E:24:72 Connected: no
[CHG] Device DC:2C:26:0E:24:72 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device DC:2C:26:0E:24:72 Connected: no